# Verify simple human readable urls in Python - validate domain name offline

Tags: python

I found a lot of questions for this, but I found no practical answer.

I don't need **http** or **www**, users should be allowed to enter e.g. example.com

Allowed:

- http://www.example.berlin
- https://example.de/more
- www.sub.example.de
- example.de

Not allowed:

- example
- 1
- :::::
- .....

problem with other questions:

- [Python - How to validate a url in python ? (Malformed or not)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160737/python-how-to-validate-a-url-in-python-malformed-or-not/7160778#7160778) (does not accept "example.com")
- http://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (does not accept "example.com")
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532344/1907997 (allows "example")
- ^([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*.)+[a-z]{2,}$ (does not allow http or sub domains)
- urlparse (does not accept "example.com")

So I think I need regular expression for this like in the last example above but a little bit extended.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

With this code all examples are working but not "example.de/**more**"

```
def verify_url(self, url):
    url = url.strip()
    if url[-1] == ".":
        url = url[:-1]
    if url[-1] == "/":
        url = url[:-1]
    url = url.replace("https://", "") 
    url = url.replace("http://", "") 
    if url.startswith("www."):
        url = url.replace("www.", "")
    result = re.match(
        "^([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}$",
        url)
    if result:
        return url
```

Comment: Show us your attempt based on all your research you have done.

Comment: Don't try to do this. You'll never get it right and you'll just annoy your users.

Comment: _"I think I need regular expression for this"_ Remember the old adage....

Comment: `example` is a valid hostname

Comment: `urlparse` is for parsing URLs, hence the name. Not for validating hostnames (which, again, you shouldn't do)

Comment: "I found a lot of questions for this, but I found no practical answer." This usually means that people a lot smarter than us couldn't figure out a solution that works. Stop trying to do the impossible. Ping the blasted URL or host if it has to be up. Let them enter anything if it doesn't actually have to be a working location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't tried it all yet!
look at below example:

```
import re
match_cases = ['http://www.example.de', 'https://example.de/more', 'www.sub.example.de', 'example.de']

URL_REGEX = r"""(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:de|com)/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+|\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\))+(?:\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?:de|com)\b/?(?!@)))"""


for text in match_cases:
    url = re.findall(URL_REGEX, text)
    print(url)
```

refer below links for more detail:

[Liberal Regex Pattern for Web URLs](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611)
and few similar answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645567/7664524

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645124/7664524

---

## Update

In your updated question you have used `url.replace("https://", "")`; this will replace every `https://` from url that means some of the url which contains refer link to other url will be manipulated too.

Comment: Thank you, almost perfect, but this is only accepting de or com, how to remove this limitation completely? or allow only 2-5 chars for example.

Comment: r"""(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:[a-z0-9]{2,5}|.)/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+|\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\))+(?:\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?:[a-z0-9]{2,5})\b/?(?!@)))"""

Comment: look at the regex part: `(?:de|com)/)` here you can include all possible postfix for domain you want to include, however if you try it with \s it will accept any string which will result to accept any domain like .aaa .aas, literally anything; the link I provided you contains all the list of domain(postfix) you might want to include in your code.