# python regular expression to extract all forms of URLs

Tags: python, regex, url

I have this code for extracting urls from text in python3 :

```
import re

myString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet https://www.lorem.com/ipsum.php?q=suas, pri omnes atomorum expetenda ex. Elit pertinacia no eos, nonumy comprehensam id mei. Ei eum maiestatis quaerendum lorem.org/132141222 "

print(re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", myString).group("url"))
```

the output I am getting is this :

```
https://www.lorem.com/ipsum.php?q=suas,
```

However I can not extract the second url : lorem.org/132141222

What is the best regular expression to extract all forms of urls in python. I want to extract even those incomplete and shortened URLs (without 'https' and 'www').

Comment: The more permissive your expression, the greater chance of mismatches. Should it match `test.fit/data2`? How about plain `test.fit`?

Comment: Yes it should extract the url as it is : test.fit/data2

Comment: URL Validation is pretty tricky with Regex. I would recommend finding a good URL validation regex, then anchoring the beginning and end to a border with `\b`, like the following: `\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+\.)++(?:\w++)(\/\w+)*(?(1)\.\w+)?(?:\?[\w=%]+)?\b`. Note that while the regex provided does match your test cases, it is VERY BAD URL validation regex, I merely wanted to present an example that partially works. Here is a better answer not using regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645124/12689629 And here is better regex URL validation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/12689629

Comment: You can also try `urlextract`. https://github.com/lipoja/URLExtract